# htaccess and mod_rewrite, strange behavior

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with .htaccess and mod_rewrite rules. This has happened when i have installed PHP 7 on localhost (i use WAMP). So i uploaded all on my domain hosting space (php7 installed) for testing to exclude problems on localhost, but the problem remain the same.

I have two languages: '**en**' and '**/it**'. Main lang is 'en' and it's on root, '/it' it's in a folder.

The .htaccess rules work for 'en' on root

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /altro/product.php?cat_id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

php:

```
<a href="<?php echo $home_url.$cat_id. "/". clean($sub_cat_home);?>.html"><?php echo ucfirst($sub_cat_home); ?></a>
```

but not for the second lang:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /it/prodotti.php?cat_id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

php:

```
<a href="<?php echo $home_url."it/".$cat_id. "/". clean($sub_cat_home);?>.html"><?php echo ucfirst($sub_cat_home); ?></a>
```

The link generated seems ok, but when i click on it i get 404 error. Why? I always used in this way and it worked fine.

*************** **UPDATE:I TRY TO EXPLAIN IN ANOTHER WAY** **************

Normally, without url_rewrite, an url example of how i need to use it to product page is:

```
https://www.example.com/product.php?cat_id=1$n=apples
```

Now with htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /product.php?cat_id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

the PHP link become:

```
<a href="<?php echo $home_url.$cat_id. "/". clean($sub_cat_home);?>.html"><?php echo ucfirst($sub_cat_home); ?></a>
```

On ROOT this works: `https://www.example.com/1/apples.html`

Now i have to do the same into the lang folder 'it'. So i create a new htaccess file into the **IT** folder.
without url_rewrite:

```
https://www.example.com/it/product.php?cat_id=2$n=mele
```

Now with htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /it/product.php?cat_id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

the PHP link become:

```
<a href="<?php echo $home_url."it/".$cat_id. "/". clean($sub_cat_home);?>.html"><?php echo ucfirst($sub_cat_home); ?></a>
```

the link generated is correct: `https://www.example.com/it/2/mele.html`
but i can't access to the page because a 404 error. I not understand it

Comment: Both of those RewriteRules try to match the exact same thing. No idea how you would think this could work, or make sense even.

Comment: Could you explain better? The 2 htaccess files are in different folders

Comment: @anubhava: i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule in `it/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ product.php?cat_id=$1&n=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will rewrite `https://www.example.com/it/2/mele.html` to `https://www.example.com/it/product.php?cat_id=2&n=mele`

Comment: Exactly the one described above

Comment: I found the solution. The path into the /it/htaccess was wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes I was wondering because I tested thoroughly this solution on my Apache before posting.